# Android - unable to scroll view

Tags: java, android, xml, listview, scrollview

I would like to ask, why is my scroll view in xml code not working on real mobile phone. I've seen here similar question but it didn't help me.I'm just beginner. Thank you.
*If you would like to see java code or code of single row in list, I'am able to upload it.*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:background="#000000">

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:focusable="false">


        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/scrollView"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:drawSelectorOnTop="false">

            <ListView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/viewGL"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true">
            </ListView>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: You're saying that it works in the emulator, but not on an actual device? And what exactly does it do when it doesn't work?

Comment: Yes, exactly.  On an actual device I'am able to see the list, like in emulator but I'cant scroll down for more items.

Comment: Have you looked at these questions:https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#safe=active&q=android+list+scrolls+on+emulator+but+not+device

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is the only part of the xml you can leave out the `ScrollView`. The `ListView` is already a scrollable view.
Try this one:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:background="#000000">

            <ListView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/viewGL"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true">
            </ListView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

In Android you **CAN'T** have a `ScrollView` and inside have another view that has another `ScrollView`. Remember the `ListView` adds a scroll when rows overflows the available space. It's logic, because the system will not know what scroll are you using

Answer (score 0):

```
try to reduce the list view width because the listview already have scrolling
```

try like this...

```
 <ListView
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/viewGL"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true">
                </ListView>
```